# How to make particular line or border or div resizable using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, node.js

Hi i wanted to make my div `resizable` as shown in the below image

[image]

As shown in the above image i want to resize my `div` which is not happening

**codepen:**https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bQGYmR

```js
$(function()
{
   $('.band').resizable();
   $('#wrapper').resizable();
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
    padding-left: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    height: 100%;
}
#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 210px;
    height: calc(35vh - 6px); /* As you give a border of 3px */
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    border: 3px solid red;
    color:white;
}
.stories-preview-wrapper{
  position: fixed;
  height: calc(65vh - 6px); /* As you give a border of 3px */
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 3px solid green;
  width: 210px;
}
.band{
    position: relative;
    border-top: 1px dotted red;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    height: 2px !important;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper" class="toggled hidden-xs">
  <!-- Sidebar -->
  <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
    <ul class="sidebar-nav">
      <li>hello world</li>
      <li>hello world</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="band">
              <p><span>Heading</span></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="stories-preview-wrapper">
    <ul class="sidebar-nav">
      <li>hello world 2</li>
      <li>hello world 2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I believe you need to include the base theme framework too, example: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">`

Comment: @D.Smania, thanks for hint , i have updated even though it is not working correctly

Comment: I have not worked with this before, but i think you should start with a basic example, maybe some tutorial, and reference to the documentation [Resizable Doc](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/) for know about his limitations and features.

Answer (score 1):

See this [updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dQPYWr) for some additional hints.

First of all you need to add the `jquery-ui.css` to your code: https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css

Second point: don't make the `band` resizable since it's just delimiter element. Instead, make the element before it resizable (in this case `sidebar-nav`). Create a wrapper for `sidebar-nav` and call `$('.sidebar-nav-wrapper').resizable();`

```
<div id="sidebar-wrapper">
  <ul class="sidebar-nav">
    <li>hello world</li>
    <li>hello world</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="band"><p><span>Heading</span></p></div>
</div>
```

Third point: it's not clear from your screenshots which elements you want resizable. However `$('#sidebar-wrapper').resizable();` seems to work if you remove `overflow-y: auto;` from the CSS.

I think there's still a lot of work to be done in this example, I just pointed out a few things that may help you get started.